# Vue -Store Comma Separated Dynamic Checkbox ids in String

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having a custom checkbox in vue which dynamically gets generated using a v-for loop.I need to get the ids of every checked checkbox and store it in the form of string with comma separated.
For EG: "Male , Female, Other" - these are the checked values.

But as i am generating checkboxes using a v-for the checked values are getting overridden.
Below is the fucntion that gets called on checkbox click.

```
updateCheckAll(e) {
 let checkboxes = [];
 if(e.target.checked) {
   checkboxes.push(e.target.id);
 }
  checkboxes.join(',');
```

}

HTML - These are custom checkboxes.

`<formfield v-for="(option,index) in getCheckBoxData" :key="index" :label="option.value">
  <checkbox :id="option.key" :value="option.value" @change="updateCheckAll($event)"></checkbox>
</formfield>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep state of checked checkboxes:

```
data() {
  return {
    checked: [],
  }
},

//template
<checkbox :id="option.key" :value="option.value" v-model="checked">
```

That is all you need to do

Comment: but the thing is custom components does not support v-model thus v-model value is never stored in checked.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the vue documentation for more details
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="jack" value="Jack" v-model="checkedNames">
    <label for="jack">Jack</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="john" value="John" v-model="checkedNames">
    <label for="john">John</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="mike" value="Mike" v-model="checkedNames">
    <label for="mike">Mike</label>
    <br>
    <span>Checked names: {{ checkedNames }}</span>

   new Vue({
      el: '...',
      data: {
        checkedNames: []
      }
    })
```

Code pen
https://codepen.io/tonytomk/pen/NWxbeOB

Comment: Custom Components does not support v-model in vue. So , i  am trying to capture value using a event, which get overridden everytime checkbox is clicked as the checkboxes are generated dynamically.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-v-model-support-to-custom-vue-js-components